# Проблема с созданием теста PHPUnit к Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, phpunit

Здравствуйте!
Помогите, пожалуйста.

При попытке создать тест выдает ошибку

```
You need to set up the project dependencies using the following commands:

wget http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar

php composer.phar install
```

Копирую этот файл в директорию проекта, запускаю, как написано, в командной строке - то же самое. 
В какой директории это нужно делать? зачем? 
Возможно, неправильно установлен PHPUnit или генератор шаблонов? Про генератор шаблонов вообще не удалось найти, как устанавливать.

только начинаю использовать PHPUnit, пока ничего не понятно, сложно правильно сформулировать вопрос.

Comment: вы работаете из под Windows?

Comment: да , под Windows, NetBeans

Comment: я так понимаю, нужно использовать Composer. Обязательно ли?  Можно ли просто средствами NetBeans генератор шаблонов к проекту прикрепить? В Настройках путь к нему прописан

Comment: Видимо composer обязателен, какой файл вы копируете?

Comment: Просто wget вообще linux команда, возможно вы скачали неверную версию?

Comment: видимо, придется с Composer разбираться, а то вообще непонятно, о чем идет речь.